# Image gallery with slider on a lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys I'm trying to replicate a gallery on [wix website](http://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/857)
Do you know any plugin that is best use for this? It's a gallery then when click it will become a lightbox with a slider inside.

This is my HTML code

```
   <div id="loyalty-slider" class="gallery">
      <div class="media"><img class="media__image" src="images/loyalty-img-01.png">
        <div class="media__body">
          <h3>I'm a title</h3>
          <p>I'm a description</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="media"><img class="media__image" src="images/loyalty-img-02.png">
        <div class="media__body">
          <h3>I'm a title</h3>
          <p>I'm a description</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="media"><img class="media__image" src="images/loyalty-img-03.png">
        <div class="media__body">
          <h3>I'm a title</h3>
          <p>I'm a description</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="media"><img class="media__image" src="images/loyalty-img-03.png">
        <div class="media__body">
          <h3>I'm a title</h3>
          <p>I'm a description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try  with  this  below  link.

http://tosrus.frebsite.nl/examples.php

Answer (score 0):

This could give you a startup: http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/